# SSRS Multilevel indexing is invisible when click on expand

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created multilevel indexing in ssrs report where my indexing is of three level.When i am expanding first level i am getting sublevel but the name of my first level is invisible and when i am again clicking on that it is visible.What can i do over there?

The screenshot of my report is
[image: This is my multilevel indexing.Here The 2 number text is invisible because once i clicked on expand and then again clicked on contract.]

This is my multilevel indexing.Here The 2 number text is invisible because once i clicked on expand and then again clicked on contract.What can i do over there?